# Inserting multiple rows, some columns with the same value

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, insert

I'm using Postgres 14.4

I have a table:

```
users
-----
id
email
is_active
created_at
updated_at
```

I would like to be able to insert a batch of users, with some columns being set to the same value for all rows:

```
INSERT INTO users 
(name, email)
('Jimmy Smith', 'jimmy.smith@example.com'),
('Dave Jones',  'dave.jones@example.com'), 
DEFAULT VALUES (is_active, created_at, updated_at) (TRUE, current_timestamp, current_timestamp)
```

I cannot change the DDL of the table to have these defaults.

The above code obviously won't work, but is what I'd imagine the DEFAULT VALUES syntax to achieve. I imagine it would be possible to do with joining to a temporary table.

Is there any way of doing this without having to repeat the 'active', 'created_at' and 'updated_at' values for each row in the SQL statement?

Comment: you mean this? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=80dde8c05fc535fa1fc082b6eaa89343

Comment: note that `name` has no column in the target table

Answer (score 2):

If an `ALTER TABLE` to change the columns' default values isn't an option, you can join the values to be inserted and the default values in a `SELECT` statement and redirect it to the `INSERT`, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO users (email,is_active, created_at, updated_at) 
SELECT email,is_active, created_at, updated_at
FROM 
 (VALUES ('Jimmy Smith', 'jimmy.smith@example.com'),
         ('Dave Jones',  'dave.jones@example.com')
 ) insert_values (name,email),
 (VALUES (true, current_timestamp, current_timestamp)) 
   default_values (is_active, created_at, updated_at);
```

Despite of being less bulky, I see no real improvement in this approach. I would still prefer to, if possible, alter the columns' default values, or just repeat the values in every INSERT record:

```
INSERT INTO users (email,is_active, created_at, updated_at) VALUES
('jimmy.smith@example.com',TRUE, current_timestamp, current_timestamp),
('dave.jones@example.com',TRUE, current_timestamp, current_timestamp)
```

If the amount of columns used in the `INSERT` vary and you're not sure when a NULL might come in, use `COALESCE` with the default value in the `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO users (email,is_active, created_at, updated_at) 
SELECT 
  email,
  COALESCE(insert_values.is_active::boolean,  default_values.is_active),
  COALESCE(insert_values.created_at::timestamp, default_values.created_at), 
  COALESCE(insert_values.updated_at::timestamp, default_values.updated_at)
FROM 
 (VALUES ('jimmy.smith@example.com',false,NULL,NULL), -- overriding 'is_active'
         ('dave.jones@example.com',false,NULL,NULL)   -- overriding 'is_active'
 ) insert_values (email,is_active, created_at, updated_at),
 (VALUES (true, current_timestamp, current_timestamp)) 
   default_values (is_active, created_at, updated_at);
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ba2a024518beb6148ea58eb681e0363f)

Comment: Perfect - thanks Jim. It's adding a large amount of users, and I wanted it to be editable for non devs.

Comment: @KevinSedgley I see. So that might indeed make the statement more readable (although not faster). I added a slight improvement, in case some inserted records do have a value in the `default` columns. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ba2a024518beb6148ea58eb681e0363f consider accepting the answer in case it solves your problem. cheers